# How to disable WebGL API to Firefox Quatum on Linux?

Tags: firefox, webgl

With the assistance of HTML5 player, the frequency of GPU usage in browser is almost zero. However in order to defense evil scripts, for example cryptography currency mining script, I prefer to disable the support of WebGL for Firefox (57+) on Linux.

***The more universal the better.***

Is there someone have some idea toward this issue? Welcome to answering!

Comment: [Have you confirmed the instructions to enable or disable WebGL, do not apply, to the current version of Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/836832/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-my-browser/836833#836833)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enable WebGL in my browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/836832/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-my-browser)

Comment: @Ramhound, sorry,it's duplicated